# Character folding for a Django haystack and whoosh

Tags: django, search, django-haystack, whoosh

I have a django based app with haystack and whoosh search engine. I want to provide an accent and special character independent search so that I can find indexed data with special characters also by using words without special chars:

Indexed is:

```
'café'
```

Search term:

```
'cafe'  
'café'
```

I've written a provided a specific FoldingWhooshSearchBackend which uses a `StemmingAnalyzer` and a`CharsetFilter(accent_map)` as described in the following document:

https://gist.github.com/gregplaysguitar/1727204

However the search still doesn't work like expected, i.e. I cannot search with 'cafe' and find 'café'. I've looked into the search index using:

```
from whoosh.index import open_dir
ix = open_dir('myservice/settings/whoosh_index')
searcher = ix.searcher()
for doc in searcher.documents():
    print doc
```

The special characters are still in the index.

Do I have to do something additional? Is is about changing the index template?

Comment: FYI, I updated that gist, and it's working for me with Haystack 2.4.0 and Whoosh 2.7.0. I'm not sure what your problem was, but the way I wrote it originally was rather brittle so maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write [Haystack SearchIndex](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html?highlight=searchindex#SearchIndex) classes for your models. That's how you can prepare models data for the search index.

Example of myapp/search_index.py:

```
from haystack import site
from haystack import indexes

class UserProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)

    def prepare_text(self, obj):
        data = [obj.get_full_name(), obj.user.email, obj.phone]
        original = ' '.join(data)
        slugified = slugify(original)
        return ' '.join([original, slugified])

site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileIndex)
```

If a user has name `café`, you will find his profile with bouth search terms `café` and `cafe`.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve the problem. However, I already use the charset filter and stemmer in the custom backend. Is this backend useless?

Comment: No, the search backend should be able to handle it. A custom SearchIndex is the wrong approach, because it doesn't do anything with the user's input data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to let Haystack create the schema for maximum forwards compatibility, and then hack the `CharsetFilter` in.

This code is working for me with Haystack 2.4.0 and Whoosh 2.7.0:

```
from haystack.backends.whoosh_backend import WhooshEngine, WhooshSearchBackend
from whoosh.analysis import CharsetFilter, StemmingAnalyzer
from whoosh.support.charset import accent_map
from whoosh.fields import TEXT


class FoldingWhooshSearchBackend(WhooshSearchBackend):

    def build_schema(self, fields):
        schema = super(FoldingWhooshSearchBackend, self).build_schema(fields)

        for name, field in schema[1].items():
            if isinstance(field, TEXT):
                field.analyzer = StemmingAnalyzer() | CharsetFilter(accent_map)

        return schema


class FoldingWhooshEngine(WhooshEngine):
    backend = FoldingWhooshSearchBackend
```